# How can I create a branch on git for testing android project using espresso?

Tags: android, git, android-espresso

I'm using espresso to test my application, and I have to make changes on code through testing.
And when I need to pull updates from repository I want to update without affecting testing changes.
So I need branch for development and branch for testing with its changes
and from test branch I can pull changes from development branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's debatable whether or not source control is the *best* way to do this, but it can provide *a* solution.

Create the branch and check it out:

```
git branch testing
git checkout testing
```

(or, in one line: `git checkout -b testing`)

Make your changes for testing and commit them, then switch back to your main branch:

```
git commit -m "changes for testing"
git checkout master
```

Later, when you're ready to test again, merge the new code into the testing branch:

```
git checkout testing
git merge master
```

When you're done testing, switch back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thanks @solarshado , But I have a lot of changes in testing branch, so I will do a lot of effort in merging, to keep testing changes

Comment: @user1573534 solarshado has the right answer, sorry but for the first time it would be painfule, than useful